# Xcode: Clear all Variables

Tags: xcode, reset

Is there a command to reset all variables to 0 and clean all textfields?

Like, if you go in the iOS-Simulator, then iOS-Simulator up in the Menu -> Clear Preferences and Contents (or something like this... in german: Inhalte und Einstellungen zurücksetzen).

That would be much easier to reset all data instead of setting all variables manually to 0.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the context of your question correctly, **NO** there is no command to reset all the variables of your currently visible user interface in the simulator to zero and/or blank.

Think about it -- the simulator would need to know some intimate details about the guts of your application, details that are probably only available only at compile time.

If you want to clear our variables or text fields or whatever, it would be smarter to have a UIButton in your interface available temporarily (for debugging purposes only, if you want) that would do what you want to do while you are testing things out.

Comment: thank you :) but now I have much more problems than before :P